# Is it possible to have a program that runs code from another program (.java file) and automatically debugs each line

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging

For instance, lets say I want to have a generic program that creates a thread to run the code from a .java file specified in, say, a JFileChooser, and runs it either line by line or up until a certain line, and prints each change from the debugger, or at least functions like one (I.E prints the value of inside of data structures and variables).

While writing this out, this sounds like a normal IDE or something I can get by just running and debugging it myself, but lets say I want an easier way of debugging than having to go through each step myself and look at the debugger, scroll down, expand the value I want to check, then scroll down again, etc. Most of the time when I debug, I get a lot of information I don't really care for, so I want to limit to only values in all of the variables, rather than it's properties, etc.

This seems like a rather big project, or maybe it isn't and is in reality simple. Either way, I want to create a project that...
1.
Has a thread that runs code a specified .java file

2.
A Thread that prints value changes in the first thread (To make it easier, I could just have a GUI and have it update each value and step. I.E (String[] names => [],["Joe Shmoe"], ["Joe Shmoe", "Kyle Stanly"], [], etc.)

3.
An ability to read it line by line, or at the very least, record the ongoing changes that occurred so I could go back and look at it.

4.
Throw any errors to be looked over to, say, another textbox that contains the stacktrace.

I'd like to know if this is possible, and if so where to start. If I do manage to do it, it'd help me debug any future projects I attempt as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As you are new here, take a look at the help-center's how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . I actually answered your question a moment ago, but you should learn how to make your question more understandable and easy to read (which it wasn't).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot debug .java files. What you can do, however, is to compile those files and output your customized diagnostics! Diagnostics are basically debugger output that you get when you compile. All your diagnostics will be stored in a [DiagnosticsCollector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/DiagnosticCollector.html) that you can even implement yourself (you don't have to, though).

What you want to read about is the [JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) utility. The javadocs explain things pretty well, I think, but if you find them lackluster (like I did back in the day) you can just google anything you don't understand. There's plenty of examples and tutorials out there.

This is what I have in a personal project of mine:

```
public boolean compile() {
    DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<>();

    try {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        try (StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null)) {

            Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(classFiles);
            compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, compileOptions, null, compilationUnits).call();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Compilation failed: " + ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    System.out.println("Compilation finished.");

    // returns false if the diagnostics contain errors, and true if there are no
    // diagnostics or if all the diagnostics are warnings.
    return successfullCompilation(diagnostics.getDiagnostics());
}
```

It won't compile off the shelf, but it should give you a nice boost.

Here's an example of what you can do with the diagnostics you get:

```
private boolean successfullCompilation(List<Diagnostic<? extends JavaFileObject>> diagnostics) {
    if (!diagnostics.isEmpty()) {
        boolean errors = false;
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("compiler.log", "UTF-8")) {
            for (Diagnostic<? extends JavaFileObject> diagnostic : diagnostics) {
                if (diagnostic.getKind() == Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR) {
                    errors = true;
                }

                writer.println("Code: " + diagnostic.getCode());
                writer.println("Type: " + diagnostic.getKind());
                writer.println("  Source: " + diagnostic.getSource());
                writer.println("  Message: " + diagnostic.getMessage(null));
                writer.println("    At row: " + diagnostic.getPosition());
                writer.println();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not write compile log: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        if (errors) {
            System.err.println("The compiler finished with errors.");
            return false;
        }

        System.err.println("The compiler finished with warnings.");
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: That is actually... very much what I needed. I will definitely be using the javadocs along with your code as a reference at a later date.

Here's a question I have though: While this tells you if it compiles fine, is there a way to run it if it compiles correctly? Like, this can help me determine if it compiles correctly, and if it does, then can I run it and is there a list of variables that the compiler stores, and are there references to the values inside of these references that I can use?

Comment: @KyleStanly any data the compiler itself generates, which are the diagnostics, will be accessible to you in the application that did the compiling. However, how to access and/or send data to the freshly compiled application is an entirely different question. This is the domain where `ClassLoader` and `Reflection` lurks, and is beyond my expertise. What I suggest you to do is accept this answer, try to program an application that can compile classfiles successfully, and then come back here to StackOverflow and ask a new question. You'll get much more help when your task is in front of you :)